# No suitable driver found on glassfish4

Tags: java, postgresql, glassfish

I am having a no suitable driver found issue on Ubuntu + Glassfish 4.  I am trying to connect to a Postgres instance on Amazon RDS.  Except I have added the required driver to everywhere I know:
-Domain1 lib
-glassfish lib
-java-7-oracle lib

Please help me.  I have no idea why this is not working.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which driver have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm such an idiot.  JDBC string was wrong due to bad copy-paste!  That said - would be nice if GF was all "hey man your JDBC string looks bogus".